# Intermittent error while adding comment and voting questions on Stackexchange

Tags: bug

This is basicaly something I am facing for couple of months. Sometimes when I try to add comment to a question or answer or try to vote question I get error

> An Error Occurred-Please Retry your Request

Below is screenshot of what I am referring to. I was trying to vote up on question and got the message. If I refresh the site by pressing `F5` and do the action again I succeed.

[image]

I am sure this problem is not with my network. How Can I report this issue forward so that this can be fixed. Anybody else facing such issue.

The browser I am using is **Chrome**, I cannot recall that I had this issue on Firefox but I will add the information soon.

**NOTE:** This issue started couple of months before. This is also an intermittent issue.

Comment: Check the Chrome console when you get the error, might be the same as http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280273

Comment: @Shanky Does this also happen on other sites in the network, or is it isolated to dba.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @Aaronbertrand this is happening for DBA.stackexchange only, I basically hang on this site only

Comment: I guess my point is, is this a network-wide problem or is it isolated to this site. You may not have enough data to be sure.